# executing Async task in Android once

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, rss

hi i need help here i have done an app with Top 10 Downloaded Apps from apple rss feed and i am stuck in something  to avoid downloading the data everytime the device rotate by getting the values of the url and limit from the bundle at the onCreate methoud

i have implemented that and saved the data at onSaveInstanceState​ but it keeps downloading the data on device rotate

here is my MainActivity code

```
package com.ksamj.top10downloader;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ListView listApps;
    private String feedURL = "http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=%d/xml";
    private int feedLimit = 10;
    private String feedCachedURL = "INVALID";
    public static final String STATE_URL = "feedURL";
    public static final String STATE_LIMIT = "feedLimit";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listApps = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.xmlListView);


        if(savedInstanceState != null) // if null means run at 1st time
        {

            feedURL = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_URL);
            feedLimit = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LIMIT);
            Log.d(TAG, "from Bundle feedURL: "+ feedURL);
            Log.d(TAG, "from Bundle feedLimit: "+ feedLimit);
        }
        downloadURL(String.format(feedURL,feedLimit));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.feed_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menuFreeApps:
                feedURL = "http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=%d/xml";
                break;
            case R.id.menuPaidApps:
                feedURL = "http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/toppaidapplications/limit=%d/xml";
                break;
            case R.id.menuSongs:
                feedURL = "http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=%d/xml";
                break;

            case R.id.menu10:
                feedLimit = 10;
                item.setChecked(true);
                break;

            case R.id.menu25:
                feedLimit = 25;
                item.setChecked(true);
                break;


            case R.id.menuRefresh:
                feedCachedURL = "INVALID";
                break;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        downloadURL(String.format(feedURL,feedLimit));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString(STATE_URL, feedURL);
        outState.putInt(STATE_LIMIT, feedLimit);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }



    private void downloadURL(String feedURL) {
        if (!feedURL.equalsIgnoreCase(feedCachedURL)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "downloadURL: Downloading...");
            DownloadData downloadData = new DownloadData();
            downloadData.execute(feedURL);
            feedCachedURL = feedURL;
            Log.d(TAG, "downloadURL: feedURL " + feedURL);
            Log.d(TAG, "downloadURL: feedCachedURL " + feedCachedURL);
        }else
            Log.d(TAG, "downloadURL: Nothing to Download");
    }

    private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private static final String TAG = "DownloadData";

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: params are" + s);
            ParseApplications parseApplications = new ParseApplications();
            parseApplications.parse(s);

            FeedAdapter feedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_record, parseApplications.getApplications());
            listApps.setAdapter(feedAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: starts with " + strings[0]);
            String rssFeed = downloadXML(strings[0]);
            if (rssFeed == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: Error Downloading");
            }

            return rssFeed;
        }

        private String downloadXML(String urlPath) {
            StringBuilder xmlResult = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlPath);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int response = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                Log.d(TAG, "downloadXML: The response Code is " + response);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

                int charsRead;
                char[] inputBuffer = new char[5500];
                while (true) {
                    charsRead = reader.read(inputBuffer);
                    if (charsRead < 0)
                        break;
                    if (charsRead > 0)
                        xmlResult.append(String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charsRead));
                }
                reader.close();

                return xmlResult.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "downloadXML: Malformated URL Exp: " + ex.getMessage());

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "downloadXML: IO Exp: " + ex.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

and this is my logcat for a simple rotation after excute

```
03-28 10:01:56.373 21047-21047/com.ksamj.top10downloader W/art: Verification of java.lang.Object com.ksamj.top10downloader.MainActivity.access$super(com.ksamj.top10downloader.MainActivity, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) took 100.789ms
03-28 10:01:56.515 21047-21047/com.ksamj.top10downloader W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-28 10:01:56.805 21047-21047/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/MainActivity: downloadURL: Downloading...
03-28 10:01:56.809 21047-21047/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/MainActivity: downloadURL: feedURL http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml
03-28 10:01:56.809 21047-21047/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/MainActivity: downloadURL: feedCachedURL http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml
03-28 10:01:56.809 21047-21272/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/DownloadData: doInBackground: starts with http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml
03-28 10:01:56.813 21047-21272/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
03-28 10:01:56.953 21047-21274/com.ksamj.top10downloader I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-28 10:01:56.953 21047-21274/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
03-28 10:01:56.957 21047-21274/com.ksamj.top10downloader W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
03-28 10:01:56.957 21047-21274/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
03-28 10:01:57.002 21047-21272/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/DownloadData: downloadXML: The response Code is 200
03-28 10:01:57.098 21047-21047/com.ksamj.top10downloader W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
03-28 10:01:57.403 21047-21047/com.ksamj.top10downloader W/InputMethodManager: Ignoring onBind: cur seq=94, given seq=93
03-28 10:02:02.331 21047-21047/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/MainActivity: from Bundle feedURL: http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=%d/xml
03-28 10:02:02.332 21047-21047/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/MainActivity: from Bundle feedLimit: 10
03-28 10:02:02.332 21047-21047/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/MainActivity: downloadURL: Downloading...
03-28 10:02:02.333 21047-21047/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/MainActivity: downloadURL: feedURL http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml
03-28 10:02:02.333 21047-21047/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/MainActivity: downloadURL: feedCachedURL http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml
03-28 10:02:02.336 21047-21345/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/DownloadData: doInBackground: starts with http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml
03-28 10:02:02.354 21047-21345/com.ksamj.top10downloader D/DownloadData: downloadXML: The response Code is 200
```

can you help identifying what i am doing wrong or missing here??

Comment: your application support both orientation? if yes then you need to manage orientation change save data in saved instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Loader pattern.  Loaders allow you to register an asynchronous process so that you don't start additional tasks, and so the Activity that exists when it finishes will get the actual result.  See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

every time you rotate device `feedCachedURL` variable is set to `INVALID`,you should save it before rotation too

Answer (score -1):

Just call the downloadUrl function when the savedInstance is null.
Define a variable rssFeed that you are getting onPOstExecute of your async task.

```
private String mRssFeed;

if(savedInstanceState != null) // if null means run at 1st time
    {

        feedURL = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_URL);
        feedLimit = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LIMIT);
        Log.d(TAG, "from Bundle feedURL: "+ feedURL);
        Log.d(TAG, "from Bundle feedLimit: "+ feedLimit);
        mRssFeed = savedInstanceState.getString("RSS_FEED");
        if(mRssFeed != null && !mRssFeed.equals(""){
          ParseApplications parseApplications = new ParseApplications();
          parseApplications.parse(mRssFeed);
          FeedAdapter feedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_record, parseApplications.getApplications());
          listApps.setAdapter(feedAdapter);
        }else{
          downloadURL(String.format(feedURL,feedLimit));
        }

    }else{
        downloadURL(String.format(feedURL,feedLimit));
    }
```

Also you need to save the feed you are getting in OnSavedInstanceMethod and set mRssFeed in postExecute.

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(STATE_URL, feedURL);
    outState.putInt(STATE_LIMIT, feedLimit);
    //save the rssFeed here
    outState.putString("RSS_FEED", mRssFeed);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}


 private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private static final String TAG = "DownloadData";

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: params are" + s);
        mRssFeed = s;
        ParseApplications parseApplications = new ParseApplications();
        parseApplications.parse(mRssFeed);

        FeedAdapter feedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_record, parseApplications.getApplications());
        listApps.setAdapter(feedAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: starts with " + strings[0]);
        String rssFeed = downloadXML(strings[0]);
        if (rssFeed == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: Error Downloading");
        }

        return rssFeed;
    }

    private String downloadXML(String urlPath) {
        StringBuilder xmlResult = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int response = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(TAG, "downloadXML: The response Code is " + response);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

            int charsRead;
            char[] inputBuffer = new char[5500];
            while (true) {
                charsRead = reader.read(inputBuffer);
                if (charsRead < 0)
                    break;
                if (charsRead > 0)
                    xmlResult.append(String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charsRead));
            }
            reader.close();

            return xmlResult.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadXML: Malformated URL Exp: " + ex.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadXML: IO Exp: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Your downloadUrl was getting called even if you were restoring data from savedInstance. Putting it inside else will ensure this is not called.

But as Gabe suggested there could be some problems if you are in middle of downloading and the state changes. In this case I would suggest you to use RxAndroid going further. This gives you a lot of control as compared to AsyncTasks.

Here is a good read about some of the best Async programming practices in android:

http://code.hootsuite.com/asynchronous-android-programming-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/

Comment: The problem with this solution is that only the first one would run.  That first one is part of the original Activity, so any UI changes it makes in onPostExecute would go to the original Activity, not to the current one.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting your point here. But If we check for rssFeed being null and then fire the downLoadUrl method it should work fine. The question is if the app already has the data, then no need to re download it on state change. If there is no data it will download. Your thoughts ?

Comment: That's only half the issue. The other halls is what if it's being downloaded. You could then have a half dozen wasted downloads going on. And since sync tasks shares the same thread, those useless downloads will happen before the last one that effects the correct activity. Stopping that is the important thing. And loaders are the answer to that

Comment: Yes I agree that AsyncTask are a pain in this regard. That's why rather than using Loader RxAndroid is the way to go. It gives us a lot of control over these kind of things. I would prefer going with Rx in this case. But since the question is about AsyncTask then thats the answer for it. Rx gives you a lot of control over state changes and hence is one of the best way to accomplish background processes. However loader is also a good alternative.

Comment: Rx android is probably the most over used library out there. Not everything is a nail. There's no reason to add all that overhead and end up with a harder to debug codebase that rx android gives you for this.